# Evaluate/Calculate a Concatenate statement using google Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, eval, google-sheets-formula, string-concatenation

I have an input from the user in the format "12mm*300*300" in a single cell. I need to calculate the same using some formula or script but i am unable to get the desired result. The formula I used directly in Google Sheets was

```
=concatenate("=Round(",substitute(E1,"mm",""),"*7.85,1)")
```

but the same resulted in output of

```
=Round(12*300*300*7.85,1)
```

but did not calculate the same. Secondly, I tried the same using google script function setformula but that also resulted in error.

```
var formul =["=,concatenate(\"Round(\",substitute($B"+row+",\"mm\",\"\"),\"\*7.85/1000000,1)\"))"];
spreadsheet.getRange(range4).setFormula(formul);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Query can do simple math on strings like addition, subtraction, multiplication and division. Try

```
=ROUND(QUERY(,"SELECT "&CONCATENATE(SUBSTITUTE(E1,"mm",""),"*7.85")&" LABEL "&CONCATENATE(SUBSTITUTE(E1,"mm",""),"*7.85")&" ''",0))
```

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets can't evaluate "formulas" (text values) that include Google Sheets built-in functions.

One option is to use Google Apps Script to write the text as a formula by using `setFormula`/`setFormulas`<sup>1</sup>.

Regarding

```
var formul =["=,concatenate(\"Round(\",substitute($B"+row+",\"mm\",\"\"),\"\*7.85/1000000,1)\"))"];
spreadsheet.getRange(range4).setFormula(formul);
```

It's not working because `setFormula` requires a string but you the `formul` declaration is assigning an Array and the member of this Array is not being built using the correct formula syntax.

1. There is a comma after the `=` (remove it)
2. There are extra commas and `"`
3. Instead of using the built-in function `SUBSTITUTE` use a JavaScript method like `String.prototype.replace`:

```js
var E1 = "2mm*300*300";
var formula = "=Round("+E1.replace('mm','')+"*7.85/1000000,1))"
console.info(formula)
```

NOTES:

1. It might also be used setValue/setValues but you will be relying on the Google Sheet data type automatic detection and some times this doesn't work well)

Related

- [Is there a way to evaluate a formula that is stored in a cell?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16303680/1595451)
- [How to use a formula written as a string in another cell [evaluate for Google Spreadsheet]](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36012775/1595451)
- [Google sheets custom function built-in function](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43827450/1595451)
- [Convert a string to a formula in Google Spreadsheet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59701209/1595451)
- [How to get a string and use it as part of the syntax in apps script?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62662753/1595451)